# Why use Declaration-Site Variance

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance

This is not a Kotlin specific question but I would like to better understand why I would use declaration-site variance (covariant and contravariant). I understand how to use them, I just do not see much of a benefit or in which case I should choose one over another and why I wouldn't want to use Use-site variance all the time.

Comment: Don't know if you have read the generics section in the kotlin docs, it cleared up a lot for me in this area.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaration-site makes it easier for clients to use a class with generic type because you don't have to think about variance if the creator already made the decision when it was initially created. When working with such a generic class the compiler can be sure about possible variance.

```
//declaration-site
abstract class ReadableList<out T> {
    abstract fun get(): T
}

fun workWithReadableList(strings: ReadableList<String>) {
    val objects: ReadableList<Any> = strings // This is OK, since T is an out-parameter, ReadableList is covariant in its type T
    // ...
}
```

Just have a look at the verbose use-site java syntax. Many people don't even know the difference between `super` and `extends` or what variance means. Kotlin's keywords `in` and `out` are a bit more descriptive and are also used in other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.I was looking at it as using declaration-site variance in a Collection but it should be looked at as a class.